# How to update a single column with multiple values using where

Tags: mysql

I want to update a single column against the single column. But I am getting this error

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

The query is

```
UPDATE installations ins SET ins.`ref_no` = ('28374310017257',
'28374210711610',
'28373411561301',
'28373410914000',
'28373410897300') 
 WHERE ins.`meter_msn` IN ('002998000588',
'002998000674',
'002999000616',
'002999000984',
'002999000710')
```

How can I get rid of this error?

**Note:**

I don't want to update them by using query multiple times, all I want is to update the record in a single query.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), to define the update value of `ref_no` conditionally, for a particular `meter_msn`:

```
UPDATE installations ins 
  SET ins.`ref_no` = CASE ins.`meter_msn`
                       WHEN '002998000588' THEN '28374310017257'
                       WHEN '002998000674' THEN '28374210711610'
                       WHEN '002999000616' THEN '28373411561301'
                       WHEN '002999000984' THEN '28373410914000'
                       WHEN '002999000710' THEN '28373410897300'
                     END 
 WHERE ins.`meter_msn` IN ('002998000588',
                           '002998000674',
                           '002999000616',
                           '002999000984',
                           '002999000710')
```

Comment: In actual, there are more than 350 records that I want to update. Is this the only way?

Comment: What is your concern exactly?  350 records is peanuts re: efficiency, or did you need a more dynamic query?  If it's the second one, some info on how those ID's are generated is needed

Comment: @MrFaisal use an application code to create this query in a loop. should not be an issue.